# Fragment Confusion

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, layout

The [Android developer documentation for fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) says this:

> "Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the
>   fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at
>   runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user
>   interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the
>   activity first starts, as shown in the next lesson."

And partly because of this I got into the habit of always using the fragment manager to add/remove fragments to/from my user interface (even if I did not want to "hot swap" them at runtime). I am 100% certain that when I tried to remove/replace "hard wired" XML fragments at runtime my app crashed with an exception.

I haven't really worked with XML fragments for months, but today, on a lark, I decided to play around and I find that I am able to swap XML fragments for other fragments and...it works?  I can't find anything online that discusses a recent change in this behavior.  It just works.

My layout code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fl_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="mobappdev.demo.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/frag"
            android:name="mobappdev.demo.myapplication.BlankFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/click_me"
        android:onClick="clickMe"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code that replaces the fragment:

```
public void clickMe(View view) {

  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

  BlankFragment newFrag = BlankFragment.newInstance();
  Fragment oldFrag = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag);
  Log.i("TESTING", "old frag is null: " + (oldFrag == null));

  manager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fl_frag, newFrag)
    .commit();
}
```

It works without any problems.  I've tried variations (putting the XML fragment in a FrameLayout for example) and it all seems to work just fine.  I even tried variations such as remove/add and just remove and it all works without a problem.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe they fixed it?

Comment: Well, it wasn't a bug, it was a feature.  But even if they changed it, the current documentation (linked above) still says that it can't be done.

Comment: If that's the case maybe try it with regular FragmentManager rather than the support, and see if it's still there. The support FragmentManager is only a mock of the system one after all, so it has to do things differently.

Comment: I haven't used the XML version for years for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the fragment itself, you're adding a new fragment on top of that one. It's just a small issue with IDs, but you're replacing using the FragmentManager on the container (LinearLayout) instead of doing it on the fragment itself (R.id.fl_frag instead of R.id.frag)

Comment: You are correct.  It wasn't obvious for a couple of reasons.  First, the fragment manager happily "removes" the old fragment; it can no longer be found using its ID (findFragmentById returns null), but the fragment remains in the interface.  Second, because I was placing an identical fragment on top of the old one, I didn't notice that they were overlaid.  

I was able to see better what was going on by "replacing" the old fragment with a new one that had a different text message in it.  The result was a lot more obvious because I could see the two different strings overlapping each other.